# CellHorizontalSplit not working in CKEditor 4.12.1

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I'm trying to split a cell horizontally in CKEditor 4 and nothing happens, but when splitting vertically everything works.

I can't figure out what to try, because with the identical ckeditor.js code, the example that comes in the file works. Please help and suggest what else can affect the operation of this function.

tag state = 0, but i can`t find where is state init